# Set bar width or color according to a third variable in data for a python bar chart

Tags: python, data-visualization

If you have a table:

```
x    y    z
1    5    9
2    6    10           
3    7    11          
4    8    12
```

and plot a bar chart on which the x values appear on the x axis and the y values on the y axis, can the bar widths or colors be set so as to reflect the z values?